# Unable to install Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

I'm tying to install a fresh Ubuntu 15.10 distro on my laptop. I boot my pc from the usb with the Ubuntu installer, On the GRUB menu, I select test without install, but when it reachs the screen where yo can read Ubuntu with the moving point below:
[image: Here, ,my pc gets freeze]

It gets freeze and nothing happens.

My laptop is a Mountain Iridium with an Intel Core i7 6700HQ, M.2 240GB SSD and a 1TB HDD, RAM 16GB DDR4 2133MHz and Nvidia GTX970M 3GB GDDR5

Edit:

I managed to install Ubuntu 16.04, but problems still happens.

When installation ends and a windows prompts you to select keep testing or reboot, I select restart and the pc hangs, I have to long press on the power botton to reboot. Once rebooted it gets the log in screen, I introduce my password, and... "surprise" the computers hangs, again.

Edit 2:

Trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 again, I get this error message [image: Error message]

The pc hangs and I can't install anything

Comment: Is the point still moving?  How long have you waited?  By "freeze" do you mean that the point stops moving or just that the screen seems to you to take too long?

Comment: The three points stops, the fan stops. You can wait for several minutes and no answer

Comment: are you using a secondary monitor when above error happens ?  If so unplug it and do the initial install with just the stand alone laptop ... if still no go my guess would be that its barfing on the open source graphics driver nouveau ... in which case install nvidia proprietary drivers from ubuntu package

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the option 'try without install': Set `root=/dev/ram0` in the kernel loading line (the line that starts with *linux*)

Just highlight the line and hit <kbd>e</kbd> key to edit.

You should try to hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> and see what's happen behind the initialization screen.

Comment: @rojoherrero Ok. I am waiting for your updates.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've had a busy time. As i wrote on the problem description, I "manage to install" Ubuntu 16.04, but when i reach the log in screen and type my credentials the pc hangs.